# Need Help Manipulating a String / Pointer in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, concatenation

Basically I have something like this (which is a working sequence):

```
    char *command; // pointer to transmit buffer

    command = "RST; ISET 0.10A; VSET 0.00V; OUT OFF\r";
    transmit_command(PORT, command, 0);
```

In concept, I want to have the flexibility to update the command in such a way that:

```
    float = current_setting;
    float = voltage_setting;

    command = "RST; ISET " + current_setting + "A; VSET " + voltage_setting + "V; OUT OFF\r":
    transmit_command(PORT, command, 0);
```

I am not so knowledgeable in manipulating pointers in C so I had no luck with my experiments. I tried strcpy, strcat, and sprintf but my code crashes since I think it's because command is just a pointer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Indeed, your `sprintf` code was what you needed.  Show us that instead.  You probably just need to allocate a destination buffer like `char buffer[128]`.  You can do a simple stack allocation.

Comment: if you're really pressed for space, and you will always report the current and voltage exactly in those four character (a ones place, decimal point, tenths and hundreths place) you can get by without a big buffer, by just overwriting the string array with most of that already filled in.

Comment: In addition, rolling your own just for this situation might allow you to leave out the code for `printf()` and brethren, besides it running faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, strings are actually arrays of characters ending with the `\0` character. So basically, string manipulation sucks in C because you can't simply adds strings together.

As you correctly guessed, one of your problems is that you do not declare an array in which to put your characters. Your first example works because the pointers points to the character array used to keep the constant in memory.

So first, you have declare an array to contain your string. If you're not very difficult, you can simply go overkill with something like `char command[100];`.

Then, in your case, you can use the `sprintf` function. It works just like `printf`, but it places the result in a character array (string).

Something like this should work:

```
float current_setting = [whatever];
float voltage_setting = [whatever];

char command[100];

sprintf(command, "RST; ISET; %fA; VSET %fV;OUT OFF\r", current_setting, voltage_setting);

command = "RST; ISET " + current_setting + "A; VSET " + voltage_setting + "V; OUT OFF\r":
transmit_command(PORT, command, 0);
```

A word of warning: make *sure* you declare a big enough array for your string. Not declaring (or allocating, if you do it dynamically) a big enough memory area can cause corruption, crashes and vulnerabilities because string functions (like `sprintf`) **never** check if the array is big enough (in fact, they can't!)

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working. I did something similar earlier but it seems I missed something because it kept crashing.

Comment: seems you never heard of `snprintf()` and others.

Comment: @Deduplicator Nope, and that despite working in C for years. :p Anyways, while definitely safer (no risk of overflow, *if you use it correctly*). It may still cause bugs.

Comment: Looks like C is not for you, because C has no safety-nets, having many areas of explicit undefined behavior. (BTW: Find me a real-world language and implementation without caveats)

Answer (score 1):

On many *nix systems, you can use asprintf(), which allocates, using malloc, its own memory to store the resulting string.  (You should free() the string after you are finished with it so that you don't cause a memory leak):

```
...
char *command = NULL;
float = current_setting;
float = voltage_setting;


asprintf(&command, "RST; ISET %fA; VSET %fV; OUT OFF\r ",
        current_setting, 
        voltage_setting
        );

transmit_command(PORT, command, 0);

if(command)
    free(command);

...
```

Comment: based off of the context i think this user is on an embedded system. they might still be using *nix, but i wouldnt count on it

Comment: This would have been nice but I'm on a windows environment

Answer (score 0):

A more portable answer to my previous one... (A nice replacement if you don't have asprintf()...)

```
...
char *command = NULL;
size_t commandLength;
float = current_setting;
float = voltage_setting;

commandLength = snprintf(NULL, 0, "RST; ISET %fA; VSET %fV; OUT OFF\r ",
        current_setting, 
        voltage_setting
        );

command=malloc(commandLength + 1);

snprintf(&command, commandLength + 1, "RST; ISET %fA; VSET %fV; OUT OFF\r ",
    current_setting, 
    voltage_setting
    );

transmit_command(PORT, command, 0);

if(command)
    free(command);

...
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try on Monday on my system

Answer (score -1):

Make 'char *command' into 'char command[38]' for one thing.  Then you can use strcpy( command,"RST; ISET 0.10A; VSET 0.00V; OUT OFF\r" ); That is, of course, assuming that you KNOW that your strings will not exceed 37 characters (plus null terminator)  Be sure to add #include  at the top of your file.